# Bing Maps InfoBox moves postion in FireFox and Chrome when map is moved

Tags: javascript, position, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I use the setHtmlContent to set the content of a infoBox.  As per the documentation the infoBox is initially anchored at the top-left.  If I move the map (even just a little bit) the infoBox jumps position.  Its fine in IE8, but does it in FireFox and Chrome.

Does anybody have any idea/experience or any solutions in solving this?

Info boxes are added in the following way (for reference)...

```
var infoboxOptions = { width: 300, height: 150, htmlContent: html, showCloseButton: true, zIndex: 99, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 0), showPointer: true, visible: false };
var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(pinArray[i].DPLat, pinArray[i].DPLong)
infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(location, infoboxOptions);
```

And then pushed to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue in FF and Chrome. The fix I used was to listen to the *viewendchange* event and then resetting the infobox's location when the event dispatched. This works in IE7, IE8, IE9, FF, Chrome and Safari. Not ideal, but it works.

```
function showInfoBox( event ) {
    var
        location = event.target.getLocation(), // event from pushpin click
        map = this.map, // my map reference
        _that = this
    ;

    // create the infobox
    var infoboxOptions = { width: 300, height: 150, htmlContent: html, showCloseButton: true, zIndex: 99, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 0), showPointer: true, visible: false };
    this._infoBox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox( location , infoboxOptions );
    map.entities.push( this._infoBox );

    // local function to reset our position
    function updateInfoboxLocation() {
        _that._infoBox.setLocation( location );
    }

    // reset only on new display of a box, this fixes the other issues of a user moving
    // the box and it being offset
    if( this._infoEventId ) Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler( this._infoEventId );

    // listen for the end event, update location
    this._infoEventId = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchangeend', updateInfoboxLocation);

    // center the view on the pin location
    map.setView( { center: location } );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you push an infobox on the map, its offset is a default one. And when the mapView changes, it gets updated with the right one ( (0,0) when htmlContent is set).